# Proof that $o(\sigma)=3$ $\Rightarrow$ $\sigma \in$ Conjugacy Class of $(1 2 4)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

How can I show that $o(\sigma)=3$ $\Rightarrow$ $\sigma \in$ C($(1 2 4))$ in $S_4$? All I have to go with is that $\sigma ^3 = I$. I considered the use of Cayley's theorem, which would mean that a group like $\{\sigma, \sigma ^2, \sigma ^3 \}$ would be isomorphic to a subgroup of the symmetric group. Could I then go on to claim that somehow the conjugacy class is isomorphic to  $S_4$?

Comment: 1) What do you know about the order of a permutation in terms of the lengths of the disjoint cycles in it? 2) What do you know about conjugacy classes in $S_n$? A conjugacy class is never isomorphic to a group (unless it consists of the neutral element alone), so you choice of phrase in the last sentences is a bit strange.

Comment: I wasn't aware that conjugacy classes are never isomorphic to a group, the order of a permutation is always less than or equal to the length of the largest disjoint cycle, I suppose?

Comment: Hmm. Some refinement is in order. What's the order of $(123)(45)$? I know it's in $S_5$, but calculating the order of that should become automatic (so as a teacher I insist [insert evil grin]). What other elements in $S_4$ have order three? How many conjugacy classes?

Comment: Oh shooting, the order is... 6? Elements of $S_4$ with order three are things whose disjoint cycles have a product of at most 3? So (123), (124), (213), (214), (234), (324), (134), (314)? I'm not sure what you mean by how many conjugacy classes.

Comment: Correct. Have you seen the result that two permutations of $S_N$ are conjugate if and only if they have the same *type*, i.e. the multiset of lengths of cycles. For example in $S_4$ all permutations that are products of two disjoint 2-cycles are conjugate. The same for permutations that are products of a 3-cycle and 1-cycle (the existence of 1-cycles is often ignored).

Comment: I have not seen that result. But okay then, all 3,1 type permutations are conjugates of each other? And in $S_4$ all order 3 permutations are of the form 3,1? So we're done?

Comment: Yes. :-) The conjugacy class of $(124)$ consists of all 3-cycles in $S_4$ (the eight you listed), and these are also (happenstance) exactly the permutations of order three. The same holds in $S_5$. But in $S_6$ there will be type 3,3 permutations such as $(123)(456)$. They also have order three (the order is the l.c.m. of cycle lengths), but are not conjugates of $(124)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\sigma$ is of order $3$ in $S_4$, therefore $\sigma$ must be of the form $( a\, b \, c)(d)$ (I will now drop the $1-$cycle). For $\sigma$ to be in $C(1\,2\,4)$ we need the existence of a $\beta \in S_4$ such that 
$$\beta (1\, 2\, \,4) \beta^{-1}=\sigma=(a\,b\,c)$$
The LHS is $\big(\beta(1) \, \beta(2) \, \beta(4)\big)$. So your permutation $\beta$ should be such that $1 \stackrel{\beta}\to a$, $2 \stackrel{\beta}\to b $ and $4 \stackrel{\beta}\to c$ and clearly such a $\beta \in S_4$. Thus $\sigma$ is a conjugate of $(1\, 2 \, 4)$.